# How to change perforce default command console window to ConEmu console

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, conemu, perforce

I want to change the default command prompt in the Perforce. I want to have like, When ever we try to open a directory in perforce via command window the default is cmd.exe, But I want to replace/change it with [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).

I have no idea How to change it in perforce.

Can somebody guide me how to change it.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to changed the setting in ConEmu to force open ConEmu console(Settings -> Integration -> Default term -> check the **Force ConEmu as default terminal for console application**) instead of cmd.exe. It worked but only when I open command prompt in windows. But when I try to open a command prompt via **Perforce** its not working. Perforce is opening the default command prompt

Comment: What have you changed in DefTerm settings page?

Comment: Please find the pic in the following [link ]https://ibb.co/bUKki8 in this link you can see the highlighted area and this is the change that I made in the changes in DefTerm setting page.

Comment: You haven't changed list of hooked executable!